# Which derailleur should I use with a Shimano 7 speed freewheel 14-34T megarange?

Tags: shimano, derailleur

Which derailleur should I use with a Shimano 7 speed freewheel 14-34T megarange in order to prevent the derailleur from rubbing the cassette in 2nd.

Comment: I've got a Tourney Megarange on mine and it works well enough.

Answer (score 8):

[This one.](http://www.sjscycles.co.uk/shimano-acera-rd-m360-megarange-smart-cage-8-speed-rear-derailleur-silver-prod18893/)

[image: 8 speed mega range]

Or [this one](http://www.bicyclesonline.com.au/shimano-7-speed-rear-derailleur-tx75/). Or any 7 or 8 speed Mega Range rear derailleur from Shimano.

[image: 7 speed Mega range]

This issue can also be an adjustment of the B tension screw on your existing derailleur.

[image: B tension Screw]

[image: B tension adjustment gap]

Comment: I think the one other variable typical on those 7 speed bikes is whether they have a mech hanger.  If they don't I believe you can get a variation on the Tourney that was the correct mount.

Comment: That is true. But if your frame doesn't have a rear derailleur hanger, then you really should be looking for a new bike, just for quality reasons.